# Norm of $p$-adic number well defined.

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

After the construction of the $p$-adic numbers as equivalent Cauchy sequences of rational numbers with respect to the $p$-adic absolute value, we define the norm of $\lambda\in\mathbb{Q}_p$ to be $|\lambda|_p=\operatorname{lim}_{n\rightarrow\infty}|x_n|_p$, where $(x_n)$ is any Cauchy sequence representing $\lambda$. But how do we know the limit exists? Can we say that from knowing $(x_n)$ is Cauchy that $|x_n|$ is Cauchy (and so converges since $\mathbb{R}$ is complete?) If so, why is this true?

Comment: If $\lambda = 0$ then $|x_n|_p\to 0$.

Otherwise $v_p(x_n)$ is constant for $n$ large enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use reverse triangle law.

$$ | |x_n|_p - |x_m|_p | \leq |x_n - x_m|_p$$

So $|x_n|_p$ is Cauchy.